# What are some examples of psychosis in people who have major depression?

Tags: depression

What are some examples of psychosis in people who have major depression? Especially how do delusions show up?

> "Experiencing psychosis can be frightening and confusing, and
>   psychosis can present in a variety of ways.
>
> Symptoms of psychosis include:
>
> delusions, also known as false beliefs or false perceptions
>
> hallucinations,
>
> or seeing or hearing things that are not present
>   paranoia"
>   [(link)](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/323193.php)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  Please feel free to take the site [tour] to find out what we are about.  What have you read online regarding your question.  There are sites [such as this one](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/clinical-depression/psychotic-depression/) which give a brief outline.